# has_many, polymorphic associations, and fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, nested-forms

### Edit

I was missing the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in my `ScheduleTemplates`.

#### I'll leave this here for posterity and my wall of shame

---

My last question was asked in a 4am stooper, so I thought I'd try again.

I have 3 Models at play here. `User`, `ScheduleTemplate`, and `DayBlock`.  The goal here is a scheduling app that allows each user to have different scheduling templates, in which they have available start and end times for working.  They can (de)activate templates as their needs change.

I also have 3 types of schedules

- `BaseSchedule` (acts as raw availability)
- `ScheduleTemplate` (their preferences)
- `Schedule` (the in-play schedule for the week)

Because of this, I decided to make the DayBlock polymorphic `:as => :schedulable`.

When my users are created, I have an `after_create` callback to create the base and template schedule objects (every user will need and use it).

```
## ScheduleTemplatesController.rb
after_create :generate_default_schedules
has_one :schedule_template
has_one :base_schedule

accepts_nested_attributes_for :base_schedule, :schedule_template, reject_if: :all_blank

## User.rb
def generate_default_schedules
  @base ||= BaseSchedule.new(:user => self)
  @template ||= ScheduleTemplate.new(:user => self, :mutable_type => 1)

  build_schedules(@base, @template)
end

## ScheduleHelper.rb
def build_schedules(*schedules)
  schedules.each do |schedule|
    build_days_for(schedule).save!
  end
end

def build_days_for(schedule)
  7.times {|i| schedule.day_blocks.build({
        :schedulable_id => schedule, 
        :from => "0600", 
        :to => "0200", 
        :day_index => i
    })}
  schedule
end
```

I know this works as it should, as the following output shows up in my `new.html.erb` file, where I want to have the form to edit each day_block:

```
<%= debug @schedule.day_blocks %>

---
- !ruby/object:DayBlock
  attributes:
    id: 8
    schedulable_id: 1
    schedulable_type: ScheduleTemplate
    day_index: 0
    from: '0600'
    to: '0200'
- !ruby/object:DayBlock
  attributes:
    id: 9
    schedulable_id: 1
    schedulable_type: ScheduleTemplate
    day_index: 1
    from: '0600'
    to: '0200'
 .... more
```

In my ScheduleTemplatesController `#new` action:

```
def new 
  @user = current_user
  @schedule = current_user.schedule_template
end
```

Pretty basic stuff so far.

The pisser comes in with the form:

```
<%= form_for @schedule, :url => user_schedule_templates_path do |schedule| %>
  <%= schedule.fields_for :day_blocks do |day| %>
    <%= day.label :from %>
    <%= day.text_field :from %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I get one label, one textfield, when I want all 7.  I don't understand why I can debug all 7 day_blocks, but when it comes to fields_for, it only displays one.

I'm at a total loss here, hopefully someone can shed some light on this! It's driving me crazy!!